# NFC frontend vs NFC controller - what is the difference?

Tags: controller, nfc, frontend

So I have started looking into NFC recently, and have a smal project that I'm working on. However, during my research I came across the terms NFC frontend solutions and NFC controller solutions.

I have to admit, I really cannot tell what the difference is. Is it just two words for the same thing? And if not, in what way are they different? It was on the NXP website that i first came across the term.

Edit: So I have done more reading, and I think the frontend solution refers to frontend vs backend system concept. I should have guessed this, but it threw me off that I could find no mention of an NFC backend solution and therefor I thought it was something else entirely.

The same with controller really. I'm now reading up on these concepts, since it's been a while since I last heard of or read anything about these things.

Answer (score 3):

An NFC front-end is an IC with all the bells and whistles to read and write bytes via the NFC interface, and possibly another digital interface like I2C or SPI. Typically another microprocessor is connected to it, which implements your application use case.

[image: NFC Front-end]

An NFC Controller is an NFC front-end plus a microcontroller which can run some application logic. The firmware is customizable, and there is no immediate need to add yet another microprocessor.

[image: NFC Controller with Integrated Firmware]

Pictures from nxp.com: the orange parts are optional.